# Bootstrap Modal don't open in photo grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a photo shuffle grid, with this grid I can select a few theme's and it  shows only the pictures of that theme.

Now I want to do the following, when I click on a image I want a modal to open. The problem I have is the following:

- The first image (with a modal in the back) opens without problems, but the other pictures (with modals) do not open probably, I see them (half) but I can't click on them.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<ul class="portfolio-sorting list-inline text-center">
    <li><a href="#" data-group="all" class="active">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-group="heren">Heren</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-group="dames">Dames</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-group="jongens">jongens</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-group="meisjes">meisjes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-group="gemengd">gemengd</a></li>
</ul>
<!--end portfolio sorting -->

<ul class="portfolio-items list-unstyled" id="grid">
    <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-groups='["heren"]'>
        <figure class="portfolio-item">
            <button type="button" class="btn button_test" value="Heren1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#heren1">                 <img src="img/test.jpg" alt="Item 1" class="img-responsive">
                <h2 class="teams">heren 1</h2>
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="heren1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title black_tekst">Heren 1</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!--Tekst -->
                            <h2 class="black_tekst">Test </h2>
                            <p class="black_tekst">
                                <br>
                                <br> Team informatie
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </p>
                            <h3 class="black_tekst">Test</h3>
                            <!--Einde tekst -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <!--------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-groups='["heren"]'>
        <figure class="portfolio-item">
            <button type="button" class="btn button_test" value="Heren2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#heren2">                 <img src="img/test.jpg" alt="Item 1" class="img-responsive">

                <h2 class="teams">heren 2</h2>
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="heren2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </figure>
     </li>
    <!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <!-- sizer -->
    <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle_sizer"></li>
</ul>
<!--end portfolio grid -->
```

CSS and JS you can find on https://jsfiddle.net/hrpj3j9t/2/

Answer (score 0):

1) Bad code provided on jsfiddle - unclear, modernizr in js code section

2)From my point of view the best way is to generate code you need with jquery. In imageSrc I mean the real path to image.
This the small example of concept:

Place modal at the top:

```
<body>
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
       <img id="modalImage" src = "" alt="image">
       ...
   </div>
    ...
    <div class="elementOfGrid" data-image="imageSrc">
</body>
```

in js:

```
    $('elementOfGrid').click(function(){
           $('#modal #modalImage').attr({"src":$(this).data("image")});
           $('#modal').modal("show");
    }
```

another variant instead of setting attribute you can generate the whole html and use it like this:

```
    $('#modal').html('');
    var htmlRow = '<div class="modalImage"><img src="imageSrc"></div>';
    $('#modal').html(htmlRow);
```